# Dynamics CRM - how to find unmanaged entities not within solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using Dynamics CRM 2013. An entity has been imported via an unmanaged Solution. The Solution has been removed, but because it was unmanaged, the entity is still within CRM and causing issues.

How can I see all entities installed under the "default" solution. E.g. not attached to a solution. I believe in CRM 2011 there was a customize button, but I cannot see the option in 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under *Settings* then *Customization* then choose *Customize the System*. This will take you to the *Default* solution.

[image]